# How can I fix the issue as: "Receiver class does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method supportsSourceType()?

Tags: java, maven

I'm working on the [provided](https://github.com/invzbl3/EnergyDashboard) project.

And I'm *struggling* with the `runtime issue` as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean supportsSourceType(java.lang.Class)' of interface org.springframework.context.event.SmartApplicationListener.
```

[Full stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/713e6f915dbb45943db0bd38dc4cc9fb).

My [current](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/1429133d3ac739ab9f0b15d3ec98c6f6) `POM` version.

My [current](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/4816003d3eaea9ec127899928f8ad814) `html` version. `HTML` file is related to `xml` logic.

Based on it, my question is the following:

1. if I tried to change versions of `Spring` in `POM` as:

`<spring-boot.version>2.6.3</spring-boot.version>`, it didn't change the overall situation.

2. also I tried to clean the project using the command in the `Run configurations` in the *following* format as:

`clean install -U`

What can be else the cause of the issue?

Thank you in advance for any `advices`/`ideas`/`smart thoughts`/`adequate propositions` on my question, if I find on my own the cause, I'll update this question.

If you need more details from me, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatching dependencies.

Your `Spring Boot`, `Spring Framework` and `Spring Context` versions all should match.

I've managed to run your project by using these versions:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.29</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.20</version> <!-- Use a version 5.0 or higher -->
</dependency>
```

`Spring Boot 2.7.0` is meant to ship with `Spring Framework 5.3.29`, and at the time that came out, `Spring Context 5.3.20` was the latest version.

Comment: Thank you, Leonardo, for your valuable input according to my question. I appreciate it. I want to clarify one thing, I have already updated and rerun after `clean install -U` own project with the [modified](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/4167d7fac34d4954d0cf797450275365) version of `POM`, but I'm reproducing intermediate issue as: 
[Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/5c753aade0ccb3525d54f6e20d2b9ea8#file-stacktrace-java-L25).

Comment: Could you elaborate, please, did you add something besides `POM` to other classes, any additional annotations, maybe, or your `POM` was a bit different from mine? Also, did you test it with database or not? Because, as I see, from my current version, it's not enough to run successfully.

Comment: After additional observations, as it turned out, needed to add, as well, `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example.repository")`, besides improving `POM`, for `entry-point` file. Thank you a lot. Accepted.